# I am having directory issue or something I don't know

Tags: cypress

```
File 'd:/cypress/gitRepo3/CypressNonGit/node_modules/cypress/types' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Matched by include pattern './node_modules/cypress' in 'd:/cypress/gitRepo3/CypressNonGit/jsconfig.json'
```

I am trying to get autosuggestions into my `cypress` code, I guess (learning phase only)
I am getting this error when I include `jsconfig.json` whish is saying as above.

I using visual studio code 1.64.2

jsconfig.json

```
{
"include" :[
    "./node_modules/cypress",
    "cypress/**/*.js"
]
```

}

[image: screenshot for this error]

and this my project structure

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[]` user `{}`
like

````
"include" :{
    "./node_modules/cypress",
    "cypress/**/*.js"
}```
````

Comment: Please read [using-the-include-property](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-the-include-property)

Comment: Just replace `{}` and try it will return your expected results or not.

Comment: You're saying docs are wrong?

Comment: If I change it to {}  I get this error "File 'd:/cypress/gitRepo3/CypressNonGit/node_modules/cypress/types' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilationts"